# Can I delete the second ' is '?

Tags: ellipsis

> A successful BBC TV programme **is** not only watched by millions in
>   Britain, but **is** seen by millions more all over the world as well.

Can I delete the second **is**?

And the sentence became that

> A successful BBC TV programme **is** not only watched by millions in
>   Britain, but seen by millions more all over the world as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89982/discussion-on-question-by-y-zeng-can-i-delete-the-second-is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, the two versions are pretty much identical in meaning.
In a slightly more complex example, you may need to include the second `is` in order to dis-ambiguate.

Comment: In spoken English, it's more common to use ellipsis and remove extraneous sentence components—everything being equal. So, in this case, the second version flows better and is probably how more people would phrase it. Repeating *is* here, while correct, sounds slightly stilted.

Comment: Can  you tell me what is the meaning of word 'dis-ambiguate' which I can not find in my dictionary?

Comment: @Y.zeng *Disambiguate*  is commonly spelled without a hyphen—as [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disambiguate). When something is ambiguous, it can have more than one interpretation. When you disambiguate it, you rephrase it in such a way that there is only a single interpretation (or at least only a single likely interpretation).